# Sending email before the remediation date

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow

I'm working on this Workflow and I need an automated message send to certain individuals 30 days before the "remediation date"

it runs when items created and changed in SharePoint 2010.

Comment: It will be possible by creating a Timer Job, pls let me know if that will be an option

Comment: @Arsalan Yes please . Any option is fine.

Answer (score 3):

You could create some columns to help you to recode the reminder date. For more detailed information, you could refer to the articles below.

The article below is about how to create a Task with a Reminder in SharePoint 2010.

http://www.aspe-it.com/blog/2013/how-to-create-a-task-with-a-reminder-in-sharepoint-2010/

The article below is about triggering a workflow when expiry date is approaching.

http://thingsivefoundout.blogspot.com/2012/07/triggering-workflow-when-expiry-date-is.html

There is a similar case:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/1e2912f4-3119-49b0-b620-e67f629596d0/how-to-send-alert-on-2-days-before-of-task-due-date?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy

You also could enable retention and create a retention stage in the information management policy settings in the task list settings. For more detailed information, you could refer to the article below.

The article below is about how to create a timed Workflow in SharePoint 2010.

http://blogs.askcts.com/2013/05/14/creating-a-timed-workflow-in-sharepoint-2010/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily by creating a Timer Job, following tutorials will help understand how to create a Timer Job:

[How to Create Timer Job in SharePoint 2013](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b8e86c/how-to-create-timer-job-in-sharepoint-2013/)
[How to: Create a Web Application-Scoped Timer Job](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798313.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

These jobs are adding items to an existing list, you instead need to fetch items from a list and check for "remediation date", to do this following query will be used:

```
string strQuery = @"<Where>
                       <Leq>
                          <FieldRef Name='RemediationDate' />
                          <Value Type='DateTime'><Today OffsetDays='30' /></Value>
                       </Leq>
                    </Where>";
```

The offset will add 30 days in today's date and get items for that date.

```
var query = new SPQuery
{
   Query = strQuery
};

var scheduledItems = spList.GetItems(query);
foreach (SPListItem item in scheduledItems)
{
  //send email, update item status
}
```

After that just query the items, loop through them and send emails accordingly.

I would suggest to add a STATUS field as well in the list, and update it once the emails are sent. In your query you should only request items where STATUS is not updated. Make your job run each hour to not miss the items.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, this is not possible with Sharepoint default workflow 2010, I prefer to use nintex workflows. create a site workflow in nintex workflow